# Impact of wait() method on a thread in synchronization block in java

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, wait

```
synchronized (lockObject) {
  // update some value of the common shared resource
  lockObject.wait();
}
```

As on call of the wait() method, the thread will release the lock, I want to know after releasing the lock does it also update the value in the main memory of the shared resource object or it only updates the value after the execution of the synchronized block.

Comment: Other threads can see what has been done before `wait` once `wait` is executed.

Comment: If we are running our code inside the synchronized block then our code is gonna be executing in a mutually exclusive way which means one thread will execute it at a time means the shared resource will only be accessible by one thread at a time and as a thread is being executed by the processor cores and cores cache these values into their cache and processors updates only these values back to the main memory when the execution of the synchronized block gets completed to resolve the visibility issue. Does the thread or processor updates the value to the main memory when we call wait() method

Comment: Yes, it does. `wait` includes a memory barrier.

Answer (score 4):

It is a fallacy to think that due to synchronization (e.g. synchronized or volatile) data needs to be written to main memory. CPU caches on modern CPUs are always coherent due to the cache coherence protocol.

An object.wait causes the thread to release the lock. And as soon as another thread sends a notify, the lock is reacquired. The object.wait has no semantics in the Java memory model; only acquire and release of the lock are relevant.

So in your particular case, if a thread does a wait, it triggers a lock release. If another thread would read that state after acquiring the same lock, then there is a happens-before edge between the thread that did the release of the lock (due to wait) and the thread that acquired the lock. And therefore the second thread is guaranteed to see the changes of the first.

Answer (score 0):

In the JLS 17.4.5 it says

> The wait methods of class Object (§17.2.1) have lock and unlock actions associated with them; their happens-before relationships are defined by these associated actions.

Also, from JLS 17.4.4:

> An unlock action on monitor m synchronizes-with all subsequent lock actions on m (where "subsequent" is defined according to the synchronization order).

If a thread waits it gives up the lock so that other threads can act. It only makes sense that any changes the thread made before waiting (which triggers an unlock action) should be visible to other threads acquiring the lock.